# Ef Core foreign key unique which is not what I want

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add a navigation property to my userprivilege model, but the problem is that I want the navigation properties (User and Privilege) to not be unique, or at least join them in one foreign key which is unique.

Here is my userprivilege model :

```
public class UserPrivilege
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int PrivilegeID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Privilege Privilege { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my  Privilege model

```
public class Privilege
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual UserPrivilege UserPrivilege { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my User Model :

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public virtual UserPrivilege UserPrivilege { get; set; }
    
}
```

PS: I want to be able to access the UserPrivilege property from user and privilege, and also the user, privilege properties from the userprivilege class.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to fix the classes

```
public class Privilege
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserPrivilege> UserPrivileges { get; set; }
}


public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Privilege> Privileges { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserPrivilege> UserPrivileges { get; set; }
}
```

if you deside to  make one-to-many instead of many-to-many you have to delete UserPriviledge class and change another two classes

`````
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public int? PrivilegeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Privilege Privilege { get; set; }
  
}
public class Privilege
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
````
`````

Comment: Thank you @Serge, but the thing is that I want the userprivilege to be unique o null for the user. A User has one privilege (rank). But I think I understood where the mistake I'm making is coming from, thank you !

Comment: Why then you created a table UserPriviledge?

Comment: You're right, I made a mistake creating the user privilege table for the moment ( I wanted to have the option to custom create privileges for my users, and to give them multiple privileges in the future), but I think for the moment it's not necessary. Do you think I should remove it for the moment ???

Comment: @Mohammed I added another variant to my answer. You can select the one that fits your needs.

Comment: thank you, I understood the mistake I was making.